# swap defaut icon as like gmail on password show hide in TextInputLayout

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

[want like gmail eyes icon[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQyAf.png)[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQdkO.png)*want icon just like gmail's password show hide , like if pass show then eyes is open and password hide then eyes with cross vice versa , same as like gmail password field , but  there is issue in default, so i want change in default icon , i don't want to add any drawable in TextInputLayout because after adding drawable default animation not works.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute in textLayoutInput named * `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`*
Which will help you to achieve taht eyes icon to show or hide the password .